# How to create JSON with column name and type from another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with following schema:

```
root
 |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Id_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Foo: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Bar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- XPTO: string (nullable = true)
```

From that dataframe I want to create a JSON file with the column name and type as follow

```
{
 "Id": "integer",
 "Id_FK": "integer",
 "Foo": "integer ",
 "Bar": "string",
 "XPTO": "string",
}
```

I'm trying to do that using pyspark, but I can't find any way to accomplish that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that first populates a dictionary iterating among the columns of the schema. Then we use `json.dumps` to convert the dictionary into string:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
import json

# sample schema
schema = StructType(
    [
      StructField("Id_FK" ,IntegerType()),
      StructField("Foo" ,IntegerType()),
      StructField("Bar" ,StringType()),
      StructField("XPTO" ,StringType())
    ])

# create a dictionary where each item will be a pair of col_name : col_type
dict = {}
for c in schema:
  dict[c.name] = str(c.dataType)

# convert to json string
data = json.dumps(dict)

# save to file
text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(data)
text_file.close()
```